# Hide page filename in href URLs

Tags: html, .htaccess, href

I configured htaccess file in root folder of Apache htdocs like

```
DirectoryIndex index.py
```

And when you open this page there is href:

```
<h3><a href='/?id=blah'><font color='8650AC'>blah</font></a></h3>
```

When clicked on, it sends me to

```
http://127.0.0.1/index.py?id=blah
```

instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1/?id=blah
```

as I want. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line in the same .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.py

RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.py [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.py$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Could you please explain me magic behind this mysterious regexp?

Comment: Oh it is not really mysterious. Using `%{THE_REQUEST}` we make sure `index.py` appears in the entered URL and `(.*?)index\.py` regex is used to capture URI that appears before `index.py`. This captured string is used as replacement.

Comment: So, when we see /index.py in requested address, we seek what was in request before it, and leave only it or what?

Comment: Yes true, this rule will also redirect `/sub/index.py` to `/sub/`

Comment: Won't it ruin post requests? Because when I have get form everything is good, but with post it just kinda not working. Why?

Comment: Actually POST requests shouldn't be doing any redirects. If you want I can add one more condition to skip POST method reuqests here.